# Is there a way to show table of contents in Windowed viewer in TexStudio

Tags: pdf, texstudio

TexStudio allows you to open a separate pdf viewer (Windowed viewer). But Windowed viewer does not show the table of contents (section panel) in a pdf file (on the left). I wonder how to set the Windowed viewer to display the table of contents in a pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. On the Windowed viewer, right-click and select `Show->Contents`. This will display the table of contents on the viewer.